# Advanced iPhone Programming Books

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

Are there any advanced iPhone Programming Books? I don't want an [introduction in Objective C, Cocoa Touch or UIKit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/449101/iphone-development-books), but a comprehensive collection of best practices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're willing to look beyond books, the videos for my Advanced iPhone Development course are [available for free on iTunes U](https://podcasts.apple.com/us/podcast/advanced-iphone-development-spring-2010/id407243032).  I describe what I've found to work best for me when dealing with various iOS frameworks and concepts.  I also list many more advanced references for each topic in my [course notes](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/sites/default/files/Spring2010CourseNotes/index.html) for the class.

Comment: Hi Brad, just realized that I'm watching you talk! :)

Comment: Thanks @Brad. Just started the whole series downloading. See you soon!

Answer (score 2):

[Erica Sadun's Cookbook](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321659570) might be what you're looking for. But it's not too advanced, also helpful for beginners.

Comment: Does the 2nd Edition removes the usage of private APIs?!

Comment: I'm not sure (own the first one), but it's always pointed out explicitly when private APIs are used.