# iOS5 advanced programming book / tutorials

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios5

As an iOS newbie there are tons of  books out there that to satisfy learning the basics. Now, I want to move over to some advanced reading such as OAuth and SQLite and dynamic API derived tableviews etc. 
Any resources out there that you would recommend?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Advanced iPhone Programming Books](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117578/advanced-iphone-programming-books)

Comment: @brad woops. my bad. also, looking through your lectures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are a couple:

More iOS 5 Development book is pretty good:
[http://www.amazon.com/More-iOS-Development-Further-Explorations/dp/1430238070/ref=sr_1_15?ie=UTF8&qid=1335388180&sr=8-15](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430238070)

haven't gone through all of this one but it's pretty good
Pro iOS Table Views: for iPhone, iPad, and iPod touch:
[http://www.amazon.com/Pro-iOS-Table-Views-iPhone/dp/1430233486/ref=sr_1_24?ie=UTF8&qid=1335388229&sr=8-24](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1430233486)

I know Apress goes a little deeper into other iOS topics as well, maybe check out their website... But you will probably need to rely on blogs, apple documentation, and other online sources for more advanced development

Comment: "Is pretty good"  How do you have it?  The first one hasn't been released yet at the link you listed o,0.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense.  A quick check confirms that it is the same author, so this is a reasonable conclusion.  I look forward to its release!